# TextWidget overflowing and the following elements are not visible on Row widget flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create widget as follow:

[image]

but the widget is overflow as like as follow:

[image]

The overflow happens when the text length is increased. all the widgets like "Answered," "29 Jan" are fallen out of the UI range.

I have tried as follow :

```
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              child: Text(
                "Tim Helmen James Bond Claffer Syllabus Mark Anthony",
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: ScreenColor.alreadyHaveAnAccountColor),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 4.0,
            ),
            Text(
                    "Answered",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: ScreenColor.alreadyHaveAnAccountColor,
                    ),
                  )
             ,
             Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 5.0,
                      height: 5.0,
                      child: Container(
                        color: ScreenColor.inputFieldBorderColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                Text(
                    "Jan 20",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: ScreenColor.inputFieldPlaceholderColor,
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
           height: 4.0,
         ),

        Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      "Doctor @ Kind Abdullah Specialist Children Hosptial",
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Image.asset('assets/images/icon-verified.png'),
                ],
              ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand your issue. Remember that we do not have full visibility of what you are trying to do, or your code. Also, you shared your code with a lot of variables that we don't have and would need to be replacing and re-coding one by one to try to reproduce your issue. If you want help, I would advise you to provide a simpler sample, with static data instead of variables you aren't sharing.

Comment: questioned edited @JoãoSoares

Comment: Use `Expanded` instead of SizedBox.

Answer (score 0):

did try using `Expanded`? it works in my case

```
Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "Tim Helmen James Bond Claffer Syllabus Mark Anthony",
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: ScreenColor.alreadyHaveAnAccountColor),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
              ),
            ),
```